# Sort Array with Two Exceptions in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an `array` of `strings` and I need to sort it before I return it. The issue is that two of those values must come first. I tried a few things  (including what is below), but I can't seem to figure it out.

What I have below clearly doesn't work because I sort it twice in some cases. I know I can change the `array` to a `list` and then use `Collections.reverse`, but is there a better way that doesn't involve changing structures? I added a simple example below

```
  public static String[] getStrings() {
        String[] array = {"d","a","c","e","b"};
        boolean first = false;
        boolean second = false;
        int left = 0;
        for (int right = 0; right < array.length; right++) {
            if (array[right].equals("e")){
                  first = true;
                  array[right] = array[left];
                  array[left] = "e";
                  left++;
            }
        }
        if (first) {Arrays.sort(array, left, array.length);}
        left = 0;
        for (int right = 0; right < array.length; right++) {
            if (array[second].equals("c")){
                  second = true;
                  array[right] = array[left];
                  array[left] = "c";
                  left++;
            }
        }
        if (second) {Arrays.sort(array, left, array.length);}
        if (!first && !second) {Arrays.sort(array);}
      }
    return array;
  }
```

**EDIT**

Using the `array` in the example `d,a,c,e,b`. After the sorting it should be `c,e,a,b,d`

The two exceptions alphabetically, following the rest of the array alphabetically as well.

Comment: Could you post a few tests or examples of how you want the sorting to behave?

Comment: We can't tell you how to fix your sorting code when you don't tell us exactly what your sorting code is supposed to result in.

Comment: Forgot to add it. Edited now.

Comment: Are the Inputs all unique? If not, then do give an example with how you would want the output to be for such cases if the exception characters are repeated more than once

Comment: Inputs are all unique, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Java 8 Stream API.

```
final String[] array = {"d","a","c","e","b"};
final Set<String> search = Stream.of("c", "e").collect(toSet());
final String[] result = Stream.concat(
    Stream.of(array).filter(search::contains).sorted(),
    Stream.of(array).filter(s -> !search.contains(s)).sorted()
).toArray(String[]::new);
```

The first part selects the "c" and "e" strings and sort them individually, then anything that is not "c" or "e" is selected and sorted individually. Finally, the two streams are concatenated into an array.

Answer (score 1):

How about implementing custom `Comparator`?

```
String[] array = {"d","a","c","e","b"};
Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<String> () {
    int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        if (firstOne.equals(s1) && firstOne.equals(s2)) {
           return 0;
        } else if (firstOne.equals(s1) {
           return -1;
        } else if (firstOne.equals(s2)) {
           return 1;
        }

        if (secondOne.equals(s1) && secondOne.equals(s2)) {
           return 0;
        } else if (secondOne.equals(s1) {
           return -1;
        } else if (secondOne.equals(s2)) {
           return 1;
        }

        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    });
```

Refer to

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html
2. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)

Comment: There are a couple bugs that should be fixed.  For example if both `s1` and `s2` are equal to `firstOne` the result should be 0 but will be -1 with the above.

Comment: Much better! now please show the OP how to use a comparator ;)

Comment: @alfasin what does mean the OP?

Comment: OP (Original Poster) stands for the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

Take the indices of the elements that you don't want sort and move those elements to the front of the list, then sort the rest of the list.

```
public static String[] getString(String[] strArray, int... firstElems) {
    // Move the elements that are not sorted to the front
    int g = 0;
    for (int f = 0; f < firstElems.length; f++, g++) {
        String elem = strArray[g];
        strArray[g] = strArray[firstElems[f]];
        strArray[firstElems[f]] = elem;
    }

    // Sort the rest
    Arrays.sort(strArray, g, strArray.length);
    return strArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is short solution based @ikicha's and Java 8:

```
final String first = "c", second = "e";
Arrays.sort(array, (i, j) -> {
    if (i.equals(first) || (i.equals(second) && !j.equals(first))) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return i.compareTo(j);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you sort it first, then lookup the two values, and shift them upfront?
Worst case would be `n*log(n)+2n`.

Comment: Is there `shift` api in Arrays? If it doesn't exist, I think code won't be elegant.